# How to make Object generator in the AnimationTimer loop JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making simple spaceship game on JavaFX. I have class SpaceShip and i want to make random objects from this class in my main game loop on random starting position(in interval of 5 seconds for example). I try to use Timer schedule() method for the task. The problem is that i can't get clear image of the spaceship, it disappears and show in other point because of the constantly looping. Can someone help me with advice how to handle with this.

My game loop:

```js
new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long currentNanoTime) {

                double t = (currentNanoTime - startNanoTime) / 1000000000.0;

                double xMoving = ((100 * t) % (canvas.getWidth() + 100));

                double x = 232 + 128 * Math.cos(t);
                double y = 232 + 128 * Math.sin(t);

                //background image clears canvas
                gc.drawImage(space, 0, 0);
                gc.drawImage(earth, x, y);
                gc.drawImage(sun, 196, 196);
                // draw UFO
                gc.drawImage(ufo.getFrame(t), 100, 25);

                //draw spaceShip
                SpaceShip.generate(new SpaceShip(spaceShipImageArr, 0.100, gc, t, xMoving - 100, (randomNum + 150)));
                //timer schedule
                Timer timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        SpaceShip.generate(new SpaceShip(spaceShipImageArr, 0.100, gc, t, xMoving - 100, (randomNum + 230)));
                    }
                }, 5000);
            }
        }.start();
```

And the SpaceShip class:

```
package objectClasses;

import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;


public class SpaceShip{

private final GraphicsContext gc;
private final double frame;
private final double y;
private final double x;
private AnimatedImage object;

public SpaceShip(Image[] arr, double duration, GraphicsContext gc, double frame, double x, double y) {
    object = new AnimatedImage();
    this.object.frames = arr;
    this.object.duration = duration;
    this.gc = gc;
    this.frame = frame;
    this.y = y;
    this.x = x;
}

private void drawShip() {
    this.gc.drawImage(this.object.getFrame(frame), x, y);
}

public static void generate(SpaceShip spaceShip) {
    spaceShip.drawShip();
}
```

}

Comment: Are you storing the SpaceShip instances in a list or other collection? We can't help you if you don't show the code in question. [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the culprit.

```
SpaceShip.generate(new SpaceShip(spaceShipImageArr, 0.100, gc, t, xMoving - 100, (randomNum + 150)));
```

Basically, in each frame you create a new instance of `SpaceShip`. The blinking images are caused by space ships being created over and over again. That won't work.

You need to create these objects *outside* the game loop and store their references:

```
SpaceShip mySpaceShip = new SpaceShip(spaceShipImageArr, 0.100, gc, t, xMoving - 100, (randomNum + 150));
```

In the game loop you just update the position of your actors (that part is missing) and keep drawing them at new positions.

```
SpaceShip.generate(mySpaceShip);
```

Side note: you can remove the `generate` method altogether, make `drawShip` public, rename it to `draw` and simply call `mySpaceShip.draw()` - it will be more evident what's the role of your methods. It's perfectly acceptable for an object to draw itself.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me a lot.